# Как получить данные из PHP-файла после xhr-запроса?

Tags: xml, php, http, javascript

```
<script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
  alert(this.responseText);
  };
  xhr.open("POST", "data.php", true); 
  xhr.send('1');
</script>
```

data.php

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Алёртит пустой массив. А где единичка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может срабатывает обработчик ошибки? Разделите обработчики, ведь с таким кодом вы не знаете, успешен ли ваш запрос или нет. А путь к data.php у вас точно верный? Может правильнее будет:

```
xhr.open("POST", "/data.php", true);
```

Так же, тело POST запроса, должно быть такого вида:

```
"a=5&b=4"
```

И необходимо сказать серверу, как обработать тело:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```